# Blender does not let me move an object, it instead selects

Tags: transforms, selection-tools

Minor problem since I can still just press G+axis but whenever I try to use the axis widgets to move an object my cursor will just act as if I was using the select box tool and select whatever object is in the background, any way to fix this? Another detail is that it only happens with the move tool.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: It seems to be a mess up with hotkeys, try File -> Defaults -> load factory settings to see if it helps.